# Auto Loan just to improve already excellent credit

Tags: loans, credit-score

My credit score is pretty close to 800 (around 780 IIRC).  I'd like to do what I can to push it over the line. Loan diversity looks to be the best option.

I'll be buying a car soon, and could pay cash.  I'd like to get a loan instead and pay it off quickly ( > 1 year) to push my credit a few points higher.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you care about getting your credit score so high? Anything over ~740 is essentially the same to lenders. Definitely not worth paying interest to get it over 800.

Comment: The only point of having a high credit score is to pay less in interest. You're suggesting paying interest in order to have lower interest payments in the future? It's probably not worth it.

Comment: ... Unless you plan on buying a house, in which case a small amount of interest in the short term could save you a larger amount of interest in the long term. However I do agree with Craig W, going from 780 to 800 is not going to change the hypothetical mortgage's interest rate.

@Steve, what evidence do you have that loan diversity is the best way to improve your score?

Comment: @stannius - http://blog.quizzle.com/2011/08/secrets-of-the-800-credit-score-club-2/ for example, and other credit score checks that I've seen over the years indicate that the weakest part of my score is loan types.  And yes, a house is in the cards in the next 5 years (thanks for bringing it up).

Comment: what's your debt to credit ratio? 7% is ideal... that can bump your score up if you have credit card usage, but not too much.

Comment: @sunk818 - I typically do almost all of my month's transactions on the card to get the miles reward, then pay it off in full each month. It's usually 10-15% of the limit.

Comment: 10% - 15% is too much utilization. If you're not going to reduce spending, apply for more cards until you get to a 7% utilization ratio. Just getting more credit will increase your score assuming your card is not always $0 (no usage).

Comment: @sunk818 - interesting, thanks! Any links you recommend where I can read more about that?

Comment: Where do you get the 7% number? That seems absurdly low. I don't know what the average credit limit is, but I'd guess it's probably around $5,000. If so, to say that putting more than $350 on your card in a month will hurt your credit score seems unlikely. Am I missing something? The credit card I use most as a $5,000 limit and I routinely put $1,500 or so a month on it -- 30% -- and I have a very good credit score. That said, I have several other cards that I use less often, so my used percentage of my total credit would be less.

Comment: @Steve   From Joe Taxpayer:   1-20% is a good utilization.  http://www.joetaxpayer.com/too-little-debt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend against this as does the article you link to in your comments:

> Now, I would never recommend that you apply for credit you don’t need,
>   but be aware that the ability to manage different types of credit
>   responsibly bodes well for your credit score. - http://blog.quizzle.com/2011/08/secrets-of-the-800-credit-score-club-2/

It sounds like you are going to get a house in the next 5 years and that can be your diversity of credit to up your score.     If you are at 780 now, I'd just wait for the mortgage a couple of years from now.